# Write register 0 to file

Tags: file

I am trying to write register 0, into a file.

One method that I have found is to use `redir`:

```
redir! /tmp/3
echo 'hello'
redir end
```

which gives me error `invalid argument /tmp/3`
and I don't know how to fix that.

Another thing I have found is to use `writefile`:

```
let g:the_buffer_raw = getreg("0")
call writefile([g:the_buffer_raw], "/tmp/3", "S")
```

The problem here is that vim doesn't just do what it says that it does. It does more than just write to the file. It removes the newlines from the register as well. 
And in the help it does say that it removes the newlines as well, but doesn't say how to change. So it's really just moving my problem from A to B.

I have been searching for hours now, wading through multiple miscellaneous solutions that at the end of the day, aint.

How do I setup a command in the .vimrc file which writes register zero to a file upon request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to obtain the register as a list instead? See [`:h getreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getreg%28%29)

```
:call writefile(getreg('0', 1, 1), ....)
```

PS: temporary filenames are best obtained with [`tempname()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#tempname%28%29)

Now, let's put this into a command. Sorry, I'll dot some dirty things.

```
command! 
\ -count=0 -nargs=? 
\ -complete=file 
\ DumpRegister 
\ echo 'call writefile(getreg("<count>", 1, 1), empty(trim("<args>"))?tempname():trim("<args>"))'
```

- The register number is passed through the count, by default, it's `"0`, use `:2DumpRegister` to use another register for instance.
- The filename is an optional parameter to the function, a temporary filename is used otherwise
- I've used `:echo` to test the command. Remove it to have the final command.

BTW, there is a last issue: when the filename is `tempname()`, we don't know which one is used... hum... I have another convoluted idea. Let's use a lambda.

```
command! 
\ -count=0 -nargs=? -complete=file 
\ DumpRegister 
\ echo { f-> printf('Register %d dumped into %s: %s', <count>, f, 'call writefile(getreg("<count>", 1, 1),f)')}(empty(trim("<args>"))?tempname():trim("<args>"))
```

Remove the two single quotes around the `call` to `writefile()`.

=>

```
:DumpRegister
:5DumpRegister
:DumpRegister foobar-reg0.txt
:9DumpRegister foobar-reg9.txt
```

Comment: You can define a `:command` to do it. See my EDIT.

Comment: It works. See edit in question.

Comment: My mistake, I though the edit was: _" How do I setup a command in the .vimrc file which writes registry zero to a file upon request?"_ My edit was about implementing a flexible command  that answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

To redirect to a file, you need to use `>`

```
:redir! > /tmp/3
```

See [`:help :redir`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Aredir) for more details.

To use this to write the contents of register `"0` into `/tmp/3`:

```
:redir! > /tmp/3
:echo @0
:redir END
```